# Reposition a div with CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to make my menu bar reposition itself from top to the left side of the screen when scrolled down, I want the menu elements to slide down to the left position (like the motion tween in Macromedia Flash)

I have tried many CSS snippets, none of which worked.
Here is the JQuery code to detect the scroll:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
var stickyNavTop = $('.nav').offset().top;  

var stickyNav = function(){  
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();  

    if (scrollTop-500 > stickyNavTop) {     
        $('#nav').addClass('sticky');
        } else {  
        $('#nav').removeClass('sticky');
    }  
};  
stickyNav();  
$(window).scroll(function() {  
    stickyNav();  
});
```

});

CSS:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;  
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    left: 0;  
    top: 0;  
    transition: .4s ease-out;   
}
```

What dosnt work here is that the div just flashes to the left side (no sliding).
Is there anyway to do this with CSS? Or is there any plugin that allow me to do this.
http://jsfiddle.net/h2ULn/18/

Comment: I hope you've defined the variables `scrollTop` and `stickyNavTop` before this piece of JS, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing ID (#) and Class (.) selectors for nav. Is it `class="nav"` or `id="nav"`?

The most likely reason that you're not seeing the transition is that you didn't supply the browser-specific overloads for the browser in which you're testing:

```
.sticky {
    position: fixed;  
    width: 250px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    left: 0;  
    top: 0;  
    -moz-transition: .4s ease-in;
    -o-transition: .4s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: .4s ease-in;
    transition: .4s ease-in;
}
```

Another possible issue you may have, and I can't verify it without seeing more code, is that the styling of `nav` is incorrect for what you're doing. You probably want it to have `position: fixed` as well, positioned somewhere off of the screen.

I'm also not entirely clear on what animation you are expecting. Should it fly in from the top? Or from the top and the side? Is it getting resized as well? All of your styling that is common before and after the transition should be in your style sheet for `.nav`, and just the things that should change for the transition in `.sticky`.

Here is a simplified Fiddle, showing a div that slides in from the left as you scroll down the page: http://jsfiddle.net/DacY8/1/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and yea i have both class="nav" and id="nav" and im just trying it now on chrome so i didnt bother to include all the other browsers, what you gave me in the example is noy really what i wished for, its a menu nav, so its visible at the start, and when you scroll down the nav also slides down to the left side of the browser.

Comment: @yassine_hell I updated the Fiddle. Is that closer to what you're trying to accomplish (or does it at least get you close enough?)